# A base singleton object in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

Is this a legit way to create a base singleton object which ensures that all it's childs are singleton as well? I want to use this in combination with the factory pattern to ensure that all factorys are singleton.

The key class is meant to prevent childs from hacking around the singletons constructor but is basically only a formal parameter.

Is there anything wrong in particular with that approach?

```
class singleton
{
protected:
    struct key
    {
    private:
        friend class singleton;

        key(){}
    };

public:
    singleton(const key&)
    {}

    template <class child> static child* getInstance()
    {
        static key    instanceKey;
        static child* unique = new child(instanceKey);

        return unique;
    }

private:
};

class test : public singleton
{
public:
    test(singleton::key& key)
        : singleton(key)
    {}

    void init()
    {
        //init object
    }

private:
};

int main()
{
    test* t = singleton::getInstance<test>();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a class to delete all your factories at the end. :) 
You need a chain of virtual destructors for this mechanism. Beside of this, I have not found other memory leaks and the instances are unique. The security-mechanism with 'key' seems also fine. I see no way to get my hands on a key outside of the static function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

class Singleton;

class Set_of_Singletons
{
    friend class Singleton;
private:
    std::set<Singleton*> instances;

    Set_of_Singletons():instances(){}
public:
    ~Set_of_Singletons();
};

class Singleton
{
private:
    static Set_of_Singletons  children;

protected:
    struct key
    {
    private:
        friend class Singleton;

        key(){}
    };    
public:
    template <class Child> static Child* doNew()
    {
        static key    instanceKey;
        Child* u = new Child(instanceKey);
        children.instances.insert((Singleton*)u);
        return u;
    }

    template <class Child> static Child* getInstance()
    {
        static Child* unique = doNew<Child>();
        return unique;
    }

    Singleton(const key&)
    {}

    virtual ~Singleton(){}
};

Set_of_Singletons::~Set_of_Singletons()
{
    for (auto inst: instances)
        delete inst;

    instances.clear();
}

Set_of_Singletons Singleton::children;

class B: public Singleton 
{
public:
    B(Singleton::key& key)
        : Singleton(key)
    {
        std::cout << ">>>> Construction of B \n";    
    }

    virtual ~B()
    {
        std::cout << "<<<< Destruction of B \n";    
    }

};

class C final: public Singleton 
{
public:
    C(Singleton::key& key)
        : Singleton(key)
    {
        std::cout << ">>>> Construction of C \n";
    }

    virtual ~C()
    {
        std::cout << "<<<< Destruction of C \n";    
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Object creation seems all ok
    B* x = Singleton::getInstance<B>();
    std::cout << "x: " << x << "\n";    

    B* y = Singleton::getInstance<B>();
    std::cout << "y: " << y << "\n";

    C* v = Singleton::getInstance<C>();
    std::cout << "v: " << v << "\n";

    C* w = Singleton::getInstance<C>();
    std::cout << "w: " << w << "\n";
    return 0;
}

// ~Have fun.~
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use CRTP something like:

```
template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
public:
    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;

    static T& getInstance() {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Singleton, T>::value, "T should inherit of Singleton");
        static T instance;
        return instance;
    }
protected:
    Singleton() = default;
    ~Singleton() = default;
};
```

And then

```
class MyFactory : Singleton<MyFactory>
{
private:
    friend class Singleton<MyFactory>;
    MyFactory() = default;
public:
    //...  
};
```